# During the Covid Pandemic why did the EURO appreciate against the USD even though during recessions the USD is supposed to rise as a safe-haven?

Tags: macroeconomics, foreign-exchange, covid-19-crisis, recession

During recessions everyone flocks to USD as a safe-haven currency. However, during the pandemic quite the opposite happened in terms of EUR/USD and the Euro appreciated against the USD all the way from 2020 March to 2021 May.